# How to integrate existing OwinMiddleware into a .Net Core 2.0 app pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin, owin-middleware

I have a handful of existing Owin middleware classes, originally written for .Net 4.6 apps, that follow this pattern:

```
public class MyMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MyMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        // do stuff
        await Next.Invoke(context)
    }
}
```

I'm writing a new .Net Core 2.0 app that I'd like to use those middlewares in (as well as some "new style" middlewares that aren't based on Owin). I'm having trouble finding good documentation or examples of doing this, at least ones that are similar to what I have (for example, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin?view=aspnetcore-2.0))

The one promising thing I have found is that the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` package includes an extension method, `UseOwin()` that seems to be the path forward, but I'm unable to decipher how to use it to invoke my "legacy" middlewares above. I realize that I should use `UseOwin()` when configuring my `IApplicationBuilder` but I'm not smart enough to get the details from what I'm reading online.

What's the most straightforward way to do this?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes (I added that link in my question), but the only example it provides uses a method as the middleware - I don't think anyone really does that. My middlewares are all separate classes and the signature of `UseOwin` makes my head hurt. I guess I'm really looking for an example of `UseOwin` to invoke (multiple) middleware classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the most straightforward way to do this is through the `UseOwin` extension method.

I was able to get this to work:

```
public class MyTestMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MyTestMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) {}

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INVOKED");

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
{
    var owinAppBuilder = new AppBuilder();

    // set the DefaultApp to be next so that the ASP.NET Core pipeline runs
    owinAppBuilder.Properties["builder.DefaultApp"] = next;

    // add your middlewares here as Types
    owinAppBuilder.Use(typeof(MyTestMiddleware));

    return owinAppBuilder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
}));
```

Notice that Microsoft seems to have pushed hard against `OwinMiddleware` classes, as this feels very hacky.

Comment: Seems to work for me, too. I agree with the sentiment that MS is making this harder than it should be.